# Best way to get Owin properties for System.Web hosted application

Tags: asp.net, owin

I want to retrieve a property from an Owin IAppBuilder instance from my Global.asax. The only way I could figure out to do this is by using MapOwinPath with a path I don't care about simply to take advantage of the callback (see sample below). Is there a cleaner way to access the IAppBuilder instance without needing to register a fake route?

```
public static class HostingUtils
{
    private static readonly Lazy<CancellationToken> shutdownToken = new Lazy<CancellationToken>(GetOwinShutdownToken);

    public static CancellationToken ShutdownToken { get { return shutdownToken.Value; } }

    private static CancellationToken GetOwinShutdownToken()
    {
        CancellationToken? token = null;

        new RouteCollection().MapOwinPath("hack", "hack",
            map => token = map.Properties["host.OnAppDisposing"] as CancellationToken?);

        return token.GetValueOrDefault(CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which IAppBuilder? What is the scenario? Where is the rest of the relevant code

Comment: The scenario is I want to reuse the host.OnAppDisposing CancellationToken from outside of Owin mapped handlers.

Comment: This is certainly a hack and probably the only way to do it. I'm not sure what else you can do. Take a look at http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/ for ideas (though you probably already did that).

Comment: Why do you not have a route?